# Is it possible to have a c++ dll run a python program in background and have it populate a map of vectors? If so, how?

Tags: python, c++

There will be an unordered_map in c++ dll containing some 'vectors' mapped to its 'names'. For each of these 'names', the python code will keep on collecting data from a web server every 5 seconds and fill the vectors with it.

Is such a dll possible? If so, how to do it?

Comment: Have you looked at [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/)?

Comment: No doubt it's possible; whether it's the best way to solve the problem at hand is a different question.  You might want to give some explanation regarding why you want to do it that way (as opposed to simply populating the map of vectors yourself, inside the C++ DLL), lest someone accuse this of being an X/Y problem question.  :)

Comment: I advise to let higher level languages to run lower level: Run C++ from C# or Python; Run C# from Python. Reversing the direction is a nightmare. It is probably easier to write whatever you wanted Python to do in C++ rather making a lopsided conversion. Although, if user runs Python then you can make a Python class that interacts with the C++ dll and allows user to interact with the dll as well.

Comment: My program is a realtime stockprice c++ plugin for amibroker. I have written a c++ code to fetch data and populate and all... But I am not confident of my multithreading approach. I am new to c++.So I thought maybe python could make it easier for me. However speed is as important as accuracy. I have asked a relative question in SO and got some great answer, but I am still unable understand the concept inside-out. I am working on understanding it...

Answer (score 0):

You can make the Python code into an executable. Run the executable file from the DLL as a separate process and communicate with it via TCP localhost socket - or some other Windows utility that allows to share data between different processes.

That's a slow mess. I agree, but it works.

You can also embed Python interpreter and run the script it on the dll... I suppose.